# Most efficient way to merge large database table into another?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a process that takes a large text file (about 150 MB) chunks it, processes each chunk, and formats everything into a temporary database (with no primary key). The whole process takes about 3 minutes.

The reason I did this was because I was processing the file as a whole, and it was taking over 5 minutes, which was crashing on the server.

Regardless, I now have this done. The last step is to take that table, we will call **temp**, and merge it into **live** continuing the autoincrement id on the **live** table (reason I left it out of **temp**? I could have been wrong to.) All of the columns are exactly the same, with the addition of the primary key on the **live** table.

What I need to do is `select * from temp group by col_a`, insert into live.

I've tried mysql processes, `exec()` commands, yadda yadda.

The problem is this command continues to run in the script that already cost 3 minutes.

So what would be the most efficient way to move about 1M rows from a temp table to a live table, as fast as possible? All while waiting for the command to finish by returning a bool value or something.

The application is build in Laravel 4.2 if it matters.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks so much

Comment: I don't know if I understand your comment?

Comment: I meant, do you have an option to run your script during off peak period of your live table.

Comment: Writing a million rows is going to take a long time.  That's the way it goes.

Comment: How are you copying from temp into live? is it row by row?

Comment: Here's the thing. I have a huge file, I can obviously process it via chunks into the temporary table, the reason being it that I have to do a bunch of checks to it before putting it into the live, I can skip the temporary table and push right into live, but if one of the chunks fails it won't work.

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT INTO table_live (field1, field2) SELECT  field1, field2 FROM temp`?  Just skip the id PK in the field list...